# Prepend items to collection view without breaking scroll

Tags: objective-c, collectionview

When I insert new elements in the beginning of collection view, it maintains the existing contentOffset, which means that new elements that I prepend to collection view appear at the same position as elements that were there before, but I'd like them to be inserted on the left side offscreen.

So I maintain contentOffset manually and shift it accordingly. However that leads to flickering if I scroll when new items added to collection. I use `performWithoutAnimation` to avoid elements from flying all over the place but that does not solve the problem completely.

Is there any way to prepend elements to collection view naturally without whole content area shifting to the right?

As I understand what happens:

1. Collection view inserts new items and prepares to display them.
2. I advance contentOffset to new position.
3. Cells displayed on screen before I inserted new items reload, because collection view thinks they became invisible.

This is the code that I use:

```
    CGSize oldContentSize = self.collectionView.contentSize;

    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            __block NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
            [objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id *post, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0];

                [self.fetchedObjects insertObject:post atIndex:0];

                [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
            }];

            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            CGSize newContentSize = self.collectionView.contentSize;
            CGPoint newContentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;

            newContentOffset.x = (newContentSize.width - oldContentSize.width) + newContentOffset.x;
            [self.collectionView setContentOffset:newContentOffset];
        }];
    }];
```

I also tried `reloadData` instead but it's asynchronous, therefore new content size is not calculated after that.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Since it doesn't seem to be possible with a `UITableView` (at least not in self-sizing mode), I'm pondering whether to try again with a `UICollectionView`.